# Почему не работает специализация

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

На gcc не работает специализация foo(const X& n), вместо неё пытается использовать общий шаблон foo(T n), в чём дело?

```
struct X {};

template<typename T>
int foo(T n) {
   return n;
}

template<>
int foo<const X&>(const X& n) {
   return -1;
}

int main() {
   const X x;
   const X& rx = x;

   int n1 = foo(0); // OK
   int n2 = foo(rx); // ERROR:
   // In instantiation of 'int foo(T) [with T = X]':
   //error: cannot convert 'X' to 'int' in return

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Здесь

```
template<typename T>
int foo(T n) {
   return n;
}
```

происходит передача аргумента по значению, значит используются следующие правила вывода типов при инстанциировании шаблонов:

1. Если выражение является ссылкой, то ссылочная часть игнорируется.
2. Игнорируются cv-квалификаторы.

В вашем случае оба раза будет выводиться тип `X`, поэтому и будет использоваться общий шаблон функции.

Как правильно указали, в данном случае лучше просто перегрузить функцию.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, не рекомендуется вообще-то специализировать функции...
Есть же перегрузка.

Просто напишите

```
template<typename T>
int foo(T n) {
   return n;
}

int foo(const X& n) {
   return -1;
}
```

Почему не работает, подробно рассмотрено у [Саттера](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=C4yxZ5ABGsAC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA54&ots=I7jISJsIMk&focus=viewport&dq=%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E,%20%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9&hl=ru) - почитайте п.2 на стр. 52-54.